# Exporting issues (no thumbnails in windows explorer)

Tags: export, video-sequence-editor, video, encoding

I've constantly had problems with video encoding when I'm looking to make wallpapers for wallpaper engine. I've tried asking on the forums on steam but they (literally the developer) aren't sure what's causing the issue so I'll give it a shot here. When I export a video with these settings here:
 [image] 
I get finished videos that do not have thumbnails in windows explorer. They end up playing fine in VLC but won't upload into Wallpaper Engine. In the past I've actually given up and exported videos as AVI and then used a converter to convert them to mp4. This obviously reduces the quality and on the video I'm currently working on I don't want to sacrifice quality. Looking through the forums the only advice I can see is to use H264, and any mp4 file should work, so I'm wondering if anyone has any ideas on this end.
To go over a couple things quickly:

- It isn't a size restriction
- Any videos with thumbnails upload fine but ones without are what is causing the problem which leads me to think it may be metadata or encoding?
- I see issues on the steam forum with other people experiencing similar issues and it turned out to just be a local thing, updating video driver fixed it for them (done that and no luck) so I am open to ANY ideas, no matter how out of the box.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out. Likely an issue on the Wallpaper engine side. I had previously exported to 1920 x 1440 to get black bars on a video, but I think it was fucking this up because it wasn't standard dimensions. Exporting in 1920 x 1080 fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

I made some tests but the lossless output did not show the thumbnail.

I think the best solution is using the high output encoding.

See the images using medium, high and lossless values:

[image]

Comment: Appreciate the idea, tried it with everything from lossless to lowest quality and no luck. Got the sound working if I dipped to anything under lossless, but no luck on the visuals. I think I'm just going to have to play with the export settings a bunch tomorrow, render it like 20 times and see what sticks

Comment: Load the factory settings. Maybe this could help.